# Bypassing App tTransport Security

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, security, transport

I know i'm supposed to add:

```
 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
   <true/>
</dict>
```

to my PLIST, but where exactly am I supposed to paste that into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create key at top level like shown below[image]

when you will select  a row in info.plist file you will see + sign appears you can click on that and it will add a new entry next to it.

[image]

If you want to add child then expand it from left side (so that you can see the arrow downwards and then click +

Comment: How can I create it at a top level?

Comment: Updated my answer, You can do this by selecting a row in plist file and then you will see list + button which by clicking on that you can new row

Comment: You are welcome, if it helps you accept it as answer